# Java Hibernate getting List from certain index or offset.

Tags: java, hibernate, list, orm, paging

Let's say  I have a list of fruits(and let's assume these fruits are in the database)

```
    myList.add('Apple');

    myList.add('Mango');

    myList.add('Guava');

    myList.add('Tomato');

    myList.add('Dragon Fruit');

    myList.add('Orange');
   //More Fruits here
```

and let's say in my domain or data access object I have this

```
   public List<String> listOfFruits(){
        return myList;
    }
```

Now let's assume that I have  1000 fruits and I called `listOfFruits` of course it will load the whole list of fruits, and assuming that we have a thousand records of fruits therefore it will load and query of those fruits and it will /give performance impact,

now my question how can add a limit or offset in an arraylist when getting those fruits? I am currently making a pagination for this.

Comment: You should post a query what you tried first. Just use `limit` in hql.

Comment: On my code, I'll just immediately call the listOfFruits() method and iterate them.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you manually added fruits to the list, these records are already in memory, so there is no much point in adding a limit when getting those fruits.

But if you use Hibernate to retrieve records from database, you can do something like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM table");
q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
```

Comment: Yes, firstResult is the starting point of the current page, and the maxResults is the number of results you want to display on one page, assuming you are making a pagination.

Comment: How do I return those as list?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `limit 0, 10` to hql if you use hql query to get first 10 records starting with 0.
Or use methods `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult` on `Query`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding limit or setting start and max result will solve the problem if someone wanted to fetch records from table in parts however if the list of fruit is part for some object like currentStock and we wanted to load this list in part then how these solutions will work.